# Split a string using as separator all characters between two parenthesis in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split a string in this form

```
[delimA][delimB]\n1delimA2delimB3
```

for example if I have

```
[***][%]\n1***2%3
```

it should return an array of

1 2 3

How can I do this?

Comment: You should probably rephrase the question to `I want to read the delimiters from the beginning of the string and then use them to split the rest of the string`. I don't think you can do that with a single regex

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post

Comment: You don't need a regex for this, a single `String.Split` will work

Comment: Voting to reopen because a regular expression isn't needed

Comment: @Lx2pwnd can you add more testcases (i.e. expected output from input)?

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com for exemple if i have `[kkk][??????]\n1kkk2??????3` it should return `1 2 3`

Comment: @Lx2pwn Can you add more examples? Can you have number as delimiter? Is there always a `\n` between your delimiters and the tail? Does your tail is only made of numbers and non number-delimiters?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regular expression for this. [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) can accept multiple delimiters, eg :

```
var line="[***][%%]";
var parts=.Split(new[]{'[',']'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8#System_StringSplitOptions_RemoveEmptyEntries) as the name explains, will remove any empty entries after splitting